# Service is failing if we add JDBC provider in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, spring-jdbc

In our Spring 3.2.3 based application, we are using DBCP BasicDataSource and it is configured in data access layer as follows,

```
<bean id="appDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
         destroy-method="close" scope="singleton">
    <qualifier value="appDataSource" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
   !--other properties -->
<property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The data access layer has ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar as one of its dependencies and using org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall to invoke stored procedures.
The web application based on Spring RESTful webservice is using this data access layer to interact with oracle 11g database. The application is deployed in WAS8.5 and it is working fine.
Now we are planning to migrate the DBCP based data source to the data source configuration provided by WAS 8.5. We added JDBC provider in WAS and the class path of the oracle driver is /opt/websphere/drivers/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar and configured the datasource in WAS. The datasource configuration was tested from the WAS Integrated console and the test was successful.

Now some of the services are failing with below exception ,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20181: MISSING MANDATORY PARAMETERS~ “####parameter name####”
ORA-06512: at "###package.procedure name###", line 2216
ORA-06512: at "###package.procedure name", line 2917
ORA-06512: at line 1
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:459) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:193) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1244) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1585) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3929) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4118) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:8721) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:4093) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1072) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1070) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1020) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 66 common frames omitted

In the procedure call that fails, the input parameter of the procedure is of table of varchar2(20) type and from java side we are passing it as org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractSqlTypeValue of  oracle.sql.Array .We are using org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource for setting the input parameters as follows,
MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
in.addValue("policy_numbers_tbl", policyArraySqlType);

Here policyArraySqlType is of AbstractSqlTypeValue type.
```

It looks like the stored procedure is getting the input parameters as empty though the values are being passed from java side.
We have analyzed the verbose classloader logs and it looks like the classes are always loaded from ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar in the server class path (as expected). The parent last option in server config or the addition of deployment.xml(for explicitly setting the parent last setting for web app) in application is not resolving this issue.

We also tried to configure the data source in the Spring configuration file as below,

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="appDataSource" resource-ref="true"
 jndi-name="jdbc/mydatasource" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

But we are facing the same issue there also.
Any help on this highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Abin

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Spring to give an authoritative answer, but your stack trace indicates you're not using a WebSphere connection.  Does the exception message/stacktrace change when using `jee:jndi-lookup`?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [UCP with WebSphere whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-websphere-2409214.pdf)

Also, refer to the blog for using [UCP with Spring framework.](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/)

UCP is Universal Connection Pool from Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Nirmala for sharing the details. I will check the feasibility of implementing the same in our project